# How do I convert an .exe file to .swf?

Tags: conversion, flash, swf

I have an executable file that was converted from `.swf`. It may have been converted with  Macromedia Projector.

How do I re-convert it back into a `.swf` file?

Comment: Doesn't the `.exe` have some command line options itself? (I guess such `.exe`s are only created for portability, not to protect the SWF. If so, then maybe it can convert itself back to SWF then?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Northcode's EXE to SWF converter.](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/02/Extract-SWF-files-from-Flash-Executables)

> No installer is required, exe2swf is
>   completely standalone and was designed
>   to run on all current versions of the
>   Windows desktop operating systems and
>   works with all versions of Flash from
>   4 right up to Flash CS4 (10).

Comment: Successfully created. But corrupted. Converted SWF file don't work

Comment: Try - http://blogote.com/exe2swf_blogote.exe 
Any idea which software was used to create the executable ?

Comment: This application same as previous. My executable icon is here
http://i662.photobucket.com/albums/uu346/ebattulga/swf.jpg
When i looking version information, 
product name : Director MX 2004
Orginal file name: Projector.exe

Comment: http://www.flash2me.com/flashconvert/ - Another alternative.